# I'm trying to get a textbox to display my string from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

And dammit, I'm getting frustrated. I'm doing my first mini-game, I think the name in english is Tic-Tac-Toe, and so, I have a main menu where I choose the option 2 players, then i get a inputbox asking for the 2 players names (i used a visual basic reference) and store it in 2 variables that i send to my constructor (?). I'm potuguese so I don't really know how you guys call it, but I'll show you the code.

**So, in the first Form, I have:**

```
private void doisJogadoresToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        jogadorTempUm = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Jogador 1");
        jogadorTempDois = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Jogador 2");

        jog = new DoisJogadores(jogadorTempUm, jogadorTempDois);

        DoisJogadores novoDois = new DoisJogadores();

        novoDois.ShowDialog();
}
```

**That gets sent to the other Form:**

```
public DoisJogadores(string teste1, string teste2)
{
        jogador1 = teste1;
        jogador2 = teste2;
}
```

**And I save it in the class:**

```
private string jogador1
private string jogador2
```

And the values get saved there. But I tried to place them in a textbox to show the players names and it just goes blank.

Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are showing not that form which you are passing values to. Here is a fix

```
private void doisJogadoresToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    jogadorTempUm = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Jogador 1");
    jogadorTempDois = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Jogador 2");

    // pass values to form you are creating 
    DoisJogadores novoDois = 
        new DoisJogadores(jogadorTempUm, jogadorTempDois);
    novoDois.ShowDialog();
}
```

Also make sure you are assigning `jogador1` and `jogador2` to textboxes. E.g. you can subscribe to form's load event in `DoisJogadores` form:

```
private void DoisJogadores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textbox1.Text = jogador1;
     textbox2.Text = jogador2;
}
```

Comment: But the values from `jogador1` and `jogador2` reach the other form. And I've tried to assign them to the textbox with `textBox1.Text = jogador1;` bu it simply gives me blank text. The values get to the second form and get saved in the string variables but then it's like they just went blank when I try to use them.

Comment: @tiagomnf these values reach other form. Not one you are showing

Comment: I forgot to add this `private DoisJogadores jog;`. And i did as you said but the second form just went blank, didn't work :\

Comment: @tiagomnf then your assignment is not working. Where do you assign textbox text value?

Comment: don't know why, can't edit the post, I'll answer here. Well, I tried to assign the textbox value in `public DoisJogadores()`, on `private void Teste()`, `public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` and on `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Basicly I tried everywhere. But got no results

Comment: @tiagomnf it's impossible to tell what you are doing wrong without seeing what you are doing. Double click on `DoisJogadores` form in designer. It will add `Load` event handler to your form. Go to that handler and paste code which you see above